# Code to generate series expansion ran fine in M10, not in M11

Tags: performance-tuning, series-expansion

I have a simple code to get a planet's true anomaly as a function of time, using Newton's method and a series expansion. (Note that I purposefully iterate Newton's method two more times than the order I end up taking the expansion in)

I have used this code for years on M9 and 10.  I just got 11, and now takes an obscenely long time to expand anything past linear.

```
    TA[k_]:= Block[{Qfunc, EoM, foE, foM},
        Qfunc[M_, e_, Ecc_] := -(Ecc - e Sin[Ecc] - M)/(1 - e Cos[Ecc]);

        EoM[e_, M_, 1] := M;
        EoM[e_, M_, kk_] := EoM[e, M, kk] = EoM[e, M, kk - 1] + Qfunc[M, e, EoM[e, M, kk - 1]];

        foE[e_, Ecc_] := 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[(1 + e)/(1 - e)] Tan[Ecc/2]] + Ecc - 2 ArcTan[Tan[Ecc/2]];
        foM[e_, M_, kk_] := foE[e, EoM[e, M, kk]];

        Series[foM[e, t n, k + 2], {e, 0, k}]


      ];
```

Then you run it with

```
    TA[0];//Timing
    TA[1];//Timing
    TA[2];//Timing
```

The first two output quite quickly, the last one takes a very long time. On version 11, it looks like

```
{0.195877, Null}

{0.15612, Null}

{174.727, Null}
```

Why did it take so much longer to find the e^2 term?  On previous versions of Mathematica with this exact same code it has always taken fractions of a second to expand even to much higher order.

Maybe there's an oversight, or some setting I need to tweak for this new version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Computing `foM[e, t n, 4]` takes negligible time.  However, expanding this quantity to second order in `e` is very slow.

Comment: Seems to be an issue in version 11.3. It's fast again for the next release though.

Comment: I ended up just updating to M12.  It works now.

Answer (score 3):

A bit of experimentation reveals that essentially all the time goes to computing `Series` rather than its arguments.  Probably, `Series` spends this inordinate amount of time checking for branch cut issues.  Using `Assumptions -> (-1/2 < e < 1/2 && t n ∈ Reals)` does not help.  The following work-around produces fast results.  Define

```
series[f_, {e_, e0_, n_}] := Sum[Simplify[D[f, {e, i}] /. e -> e0] e^i/i!, {i, 0, n}]
```

and use it instead of `Series` in the code in the question.  Runtime is reduced by more than three orders of magnitude.

```
TA[2] // Timing
(* {0.078125, n t + 2 e Sin[n t] + 
              5/2 e^2 Cos[(n t)/2] (-Sin[(n t)/2] + Sin[(3 n t)/2])} *)
```

(Be sure to run `Simplify` on the answer obtained with `Series` before comparing results.)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) on the whole expression, you can replace `e` with a [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData) expression:

```
res = foM[e + O[e]^3, t n, 4] //Simplify; //AbsoluteTiming
res //TeXForm
```

> {0.000169, Null}
>
> $n t+2 e \sin (n t)+\frac{5}{2} e^2 \left(\sin \left(\frac{3 n t}{2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{n
>    t}{2}\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{n t}{2}\right)+O\left(e^3\right)$